# Angular Routing - It is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've made a app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FeaturesComponent } from './components/features/features.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: 'features', component: FeaturesComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './components/content/content.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './components/navigation/navigation.component';

import { FeaturesComponent } from './components/features/features.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FeaturesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my app template

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header-root></header-root>
        <content-root>
            <router-outlet>

            </router-outlet>
        </content-root>
        <footer-root></footer-root>
    </div>
```

The problem is that my app is not rendering anything of the routes, I'm seeing my header and footer components, but the content component isnt filled with either the HomeComponent or the FeaturesComponent..

I am using a tags with routerLink attributes for navigating. I've tried navigating by using a hashtag in the browser, and without, nothing seems to work.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong here..

Comment: Can you show us template of `content-root` component?

Comment: Are you doing a <ng-content> inside content root? Router-outlet data will be replaced by contentroot template unless you include it somewhere inside contentroot. And where are the routerLink's defined? I have noticed issues of routerLink not working when defined inside different component. Try keeping the routerLink directly within the app component template and see if it works.

Comment: @Laurens: Did you try this: `const routes: Routes = [ { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}, { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, { path: 'features', component: FeaturesComponent }
]` Should work this way.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to achieve, `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` needs to actually be inside the template of `<content-root>`, I don't believe you can wrap components the way you have it.